# Submit FormData to php from a form created by javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I have created a single page application using javascript/jquery/ajax and php [single page application w/ add document button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWqT8.png)

Once I click the add document button, a dynamic form created by a javascript function will display [dynamic form created by javascript function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH5tj.png)

The FormData must be submited to a separate php code once I click the Add Document button, but I can't submit the FormData and the page will refresh.

```js
//function that will create a form
function addDocument(obj){
        var category=obj.value;
        var btnId=obj.id;
        console.log(obj.id);
            $('.centercon').html("<div class='maincontent'></div>"+
            "<div class='filecontent'><h1></h1></div>");

            $('.filecontent').html("<i class='fa fa-folder-o'></i>"+category+"/..."+
            "<form class='file' method='POST' action='' id='document' enctype='multipart/form-data'>"+
            "<input type='hidden' name='category' value='"+category+"'/>"+
            "<input type='hidden' name='buttonID' value='"+btnId+"'/>"+
            "<button class='btn btn-success adddocument' type='submit'>Add Document</button>"+
            "<div class='row'><div class='col-lg-4'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='docuName' placeholder='Document Name'></div>"+
            "<div class='col-lg-4'><input type='text' name='designate' class='form-control' placeholder='Designation'></div>"+
            "<div class='col-lg-4'><input type='text' name='addInfo' class='form-control' placeholder='Additional Details'></div></div>"+
            "<input type='file' class='form-control fileInput' name='document' placeholder='Additional Details' onchange='readURL(this);'><hr>"+
            " <img id='previewDocument' src='#' width='100%' alt='Preview Document'/></form>");
        }
```

```js
//function for submitting a FormData once the Add Document button was pressed
$("#document").on('submit',(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();  
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/main.php",    
                    type: "POST",          
                    data:  new FormData(this),   
                    contentType: false,         
                    cache: false,     
                    processData:false,     
                    success: function(data)    
                    {

                            
                    }         
               });
            }));
```

I have tried to submit a form directly using only php and it is works. I also tried to create a separate page with the form and the function to submit the FormData but it also works.

Can you please tell me what do or give some alternative way to create my single page application.

Comment: What specifically is happening when you submit?

Comment: The FormData will be submitted to the separate php code for mysql db

Comment: You mean that is what you want to happen.  Right now, I am guessing you click the button and nothing happens?

Comment: The only question you are asking is for an alternate way to create your single page application.  You need to specifically state what it is currently doing and what you would like it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dynamically adding the form to the dom, you'll want to change your submit handler to something like this.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('submit', '#document', function (e) {
        //do stuff
    });
}
```

See more here [jQuery on event](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I tend to always us $(document).on because the majority of the content I create is dynamic, never fails! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code many times and the result was as same as you received,
but with a small change you can achieve what you want

in the tag form put this attribute :

```
<form onsubmit="yourFunction(event)" class='file' method='POST' action='' id='document' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

then make yourFunction in js code and don't forget to put event.preventDefault(); in it

```
function yourFunction(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   //...
}
```

I hope it will help you.